# Como creo un JPAController From Entity pero en IntellijIDEA

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, jpa, eclipselink

Es que deje de usar NetBeans para actualizarme a intelliJ pero se me ha dificultado un poco su uso entre ellos esta la automatización de código, quería saber que dentro del campo de JPA como puedo crear un controlador de una Entity en este IDE y que agregue las funciones CRUD, tal como lo hace NetBeans